# How to set the minSdkVersion in Manifest.json (Android/Ionic)

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I did update my config.xml with the following

```
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="23" />
```

However, when the apk is created (and the platform with `ionic cordova platform add android`)

in the Manifest.json, the min version is set to `16`

I have this in my package.json

```
"cordova-android": "6.4.0"
```

even though, I don't think it's related.

What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 7):

In your **config.xml** file

for android, you can set like this

```
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="14"/>
```

for Ios

```
<preference name="deployment-target" value="7.0" />
```

Answer (score 3):

The likely culprit is a gradle file somewhere in your project.  Some plugins can specify preferences that conflict with your `config.xml`.  You can override all of the gradle files by passing `--gradleArg=-PcdvMinSdkVersion=23` in your build/run commands.

Give the following a shot:
`ionic cordova build android -- --gradleArg=-PcdvMinSdkVersion=23`

That should force the minSdkVersion to be 23 in your apk